# How are methods from the Iterator interface called during a foreach loop, and what happens with their return values?

Tags: php, oop, interface, iterator

I'm trying to understand object iteration in PHP.

How and when are the methods `current()`; `key()`, `next()` and `valid()` called? Are their return values used for anything?

I come across following code example from the  [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php#language.oop5.iterations) :

```
<?php
class MyIterator implements Iterator
{
    private $var = array();

    public function __construct($array)
    {
        if (is_array($array)) {
            $this->var = $array;
        }
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        echo "rewinding\n";
        reset($this->var);
    }

    public function current()
    {
        $var = current($this->var);
        echo "current: $var\n";
        return $var;
    }

    public function key() 
    {
        $var = key($this->var);
        echo "key: $var\n";
        return $var;
    }

    public function next() 
    {
        $var = next($this->var);
        echo "next: $var\n";
        return $var;
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        $key = key($this->var);
        $var = ($key !== NULL && $key !== FALSE);
        echo "valid: $var\n";
        return $var;
    }

}

$values = array(1,2,3);
$it = new MyIterator($values);

foreach ($it as $a => $b) {
    print "$a: $b\n";
}
```

Output of the above program is :

```
rewinding
valid: 1
current: 1
key: 0
0: 1
next: 2
valid: 1
current: 2
key: 1
1: 2
next: 3
valid: 1
current: 3
key: 2
2: 3
next:
valid:
```

I'm using **PHP 7.3.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values returned by these four methods are using as follows during a `foreach` iteration:

1. At the beggining of each iteration `valid()` is called. If it returns `false`, the loop exits. This value is not stored anywhere and is lost.
2. On each iteration, the loop variables (`$a` and `$b` in your example), are initialized calling `current()` and `key()` .

   a. `$a = key()`

   b. `$b = current()`.
3. After the body of the loop runs, `next()` is called. Whatever `next()` returns is ignored. If you actually look at the `Iterator` [interface definition](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), you'll see that `next()` is defined as returning `void`:

```php
 Iterator extends Traversable {
    /* Methods */
    abstract public current ( void ) : mixed
    abstract public key ( void ) : scalar
    abstract public next ( void ) : void
    abstract public rewind ( void ) : void
    abstract public valid ( void ) : bool
}
```

That you are using PHP 7.3 is not relevant. This behavior has been the same for the last 15 years, approximately.